# Matlab : convert a uint8 matrix (made of 0 and 1) to export as binary data

Tags: matlab, dll, binary-data

### My problem :

I have a 1920x1080 uint8 matrix made of zeros and ones in Matlab. Let's call it my "image". What I want to do is exporting this image as binary, meaning that each byte of the output should contain the information of 8 pixels. **In short : I want 1bit per pixel.**

If I understood well, I can't just convert it to a binary in Matlab with the "logical(...)" function because logicals are still stored as 8bits in memory (although their value can only be 0 or 1 of course).

### Why do I need this ?

I want to export the image through a ".dll" that accepts the image in a specific format (for a faster transfer to a usb device).

### The format of the output :

Here is what the ".dll" is expecting : (1 byte = 8 consecutive bits)

- the image reads from left to right, then top to bottom (usual convention)
- every byte of data represents 8 pixels,  e.g.

  - (1st byte) = [px8|px7|...|px1]
  - (2nd byte) = [px16|px15|...|px9]
  - and so on.
- note that every line of the image has 1920 pixels (which can be divided by 8, 1920/8=240) so there are 240 bytes per line of image

### My question :

How should I reorganize the data ? I guess it depends on how Matlab stores data in memory (and then sends it to any ".dll")? I have no idea about that...

Here is the code I would use if no memory tricks were to be expected. The idea is to take every 8 pixels and build a 8bit value with them in the correct order, e.g. these pixel values (1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0) would become 65 (expressed in decimal). Then I would send the new matrix to the ".dll" and hope it works.

```
FinalImage=zeros(1920,240); % 240 = number of bytes per line
for myRow=1:1080
    for myByte=1:240 
        currentByte=0;
        for myBit=0:7
            currentByte=currentByte + 2^(7-myBit) * Image(myRow, 1 + 8*(myByte-1) + myBit );
        end
        FinalImage(myRow, myByte) = currentByte;
    end
end
```

### Solution :

With the help of [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar), I finally forgot the loops and preferred this simple code:

```
% convert every 8 pixels (values 0 or 1) in a row to one single pixel (value 0 to 255)
% (bi2de option used : "left most significant bit" in my case)
% (make sure the width of your image is a multiple of 8)

vect=bi2de(reshape(input_img',8,[])','left-msb');
img=reshape(vect,img_width/8,[])';
```

This solution might be helpfull for somebody else, one day or another !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `input_image` is the input binary matrix and `output_dll_filepath` is the path to the output `dll` file, you may try this `cell-array` approach -

**Code**

```
%// Convert to 8-bit data
[M,N] = size(input_image)
cell1 = mat2cell(input_image,ones(1,M),8.*ones(1,N/8))
output_data = cellfun(@(x) bin2dec(num2str(fliplr(x),'%1d')),cell1);
output_data = reshape(output_data',[],1)

%// Write the 8-bit data as a dll file
fid = fopen(output_dll_filepath , 'w');
fwrite(fid, output_data, 'uint8');
fclose(fid);
```

Or use -

```
output_data = bin2dec(fliplr(num2str(reshape(input_image',8,[])','%1d')))
```

and then use `Write the 8-bit data as a dll file` used earlier as it was.

---

Or simply this -

```
fid = fopen(output_dll_filepath , 'w');
fwrite(fid, reshape(input_image',8,[]), 'ubit1');
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made a mistake saying that I used a dll, in fact I use a library linked to a dll. I call its functions from Matalb with calllib(...). My output data should be an argument of this calllib call. (so fopen and fwrite don't fit this case)
Anyway, your 2nd solution helped me a lot but the code is still quite slow for a 1080*1920 matrix (I have 1024 of these matrices to load). I go on searching. :)

Comment: @GhislainBugnicourt The second solution must be fast as it avoids cell arrays as used in earlier approaches, but if you are working with 1024 such matrices, then you are calling such a code that many times and performing 1024 I/O operations to the slow hard drive. Can't you write to one file for all those 1024 matrices combined?

Comment: I finally made several changes (including combining all matrices with the cat() function before sending them in one block to the library, as you proposed) but the key to the problem was this line : **vect=bi2de(reshape(input_img',8,[])','left-msb');**. It is adapted from your answer so I choose your solution but I add the real answer in the question itself. Thanks !